# Is it possible to verify the domain that a cookie was set for using Rails integration tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cookies, dns, subdomain

I'm using the following technique to set a wild-card cookie for our domain:

```
cookies['root_domain_flash_warning'] = {
  'value' => 'mistakes have been made!',
  'domain' => ".#{APP_DOMAIN}",
  'expires' => 2.minutes.from_now
}
```

Which seems to work handily.  Unfortunately I can't seem to look up anything but the value associated with the 'value' key in the hash passed to CookieJar#[]= because of the fact that CookieJar#[] doesn't actually return the options hash passed to its reciprocal method.

Does anyone know of a way of verifying the domain a cookie has been set for in a functional test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the value of the `Set-Cookie` header which can be accessed in `@response.headers['Set-Cookie']`.

Try something along these lines:

```
def test_something
  get '/my_action'
  assert_equal ["root_domain_flash_warning=mistakes+have+been+made!; domain=.mydomain.com; path=/; expires=Fri, 07-Aug-2009 11:42:21 GMT"], @response.headers['Set-Cookie']
end
```

You can't extract these values from the `cookies` method, unfortunately.  In the `ActionController::Integration::Session#process` source (`actionpack/lib/action_controller/integration.rb`), the integration test cookies are processes as below, which only extracts the `value` part of the input hash:

```
(@headers['Set-Cookie'] || "").split("\n").each do |cookie|
  name, value = cookie.match(/^([^=]*)=([^;]*);/)[1,2]
  @cookies[name] = value
end
```